# Is it possible to clean install mac os and backup on the same drive in a different partition

Tags: macos, mac, backup, install

Just wondering if it's possible to clean install mac os (mojave) while also backing up some files on a different volume/partition on the same drive or will I have to wipe the entire drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but I wouldn’t consider it safe. There are too many things that could go wrong.

- When you erase the old system, you’ll need to be very careful to erase the old *volume*, not the entire drive. Exactly how you’d do that depends on how you’re doing the reinstallation.
- If something goes wrong during the reinstall, it might get wiped out anyway.

So, if you don’t want to lose those files, you really should have them backed up (and verified) *somewhere else*. Actually, that’s true anyway, but it’s especially important when you’re doing something dangerous like a reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental problem with backing up to a partition on the same drive as the source data: "What happens if the drive fails?" You lose everything.

Backups are about extra copies: if you delete a file, you still have a copy on your backup.

If your system drive dies, you still have data on another device.

If your computer is stolen, you still have data somewhere else.

If your house burns down, you still have data on your off-site backup or cloud storage.